# Numpy return recarray with 'column headings' and 'dtype'?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am following this example explicitly:

> http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput#head-d528c8c74e765542c351a768b47c7bc9a2ca8e85

```
import numpy
def readarray(filename, dtype, separator=','):
   """ Read a file with an arbitrary number of columns.
       The type of data in each column is arbitrary
       It will be cast to the given dtype at runtime
   """
   cast = numpy.cast
   data = [[] for dummy in xrange(len(dtype))]
   for line in open(filename, 'r'):
       fields = line.strip().split(separator)
       for i, number in enumerate(fields):
           data[i].append(number)
   for i in xrange(len(dtype)):
       data[i] = cast[dtype[i]](data[i])
   return numpy.rec.array(data, dtype=dtype)

datadescribe = numpy.dtype([('column1', 'i4'),
                            ('column2', 'i4'),
                            ('column3', 'S'),
                            ('column4', 'S'),
                            ('column5', 'i4'),
                           ])

print readarray("results.csv", datadescribe)
```

Here is results.csv:

```
22,2,C,G,6
4,1,G,T,7
11,1,G,-,7
23,1,G,T,7
```

Here is the printed statement:

```
[(22, 2, '', '', 6)
 (4, 1, '', '', 7)
 (11, 1, '', '', 7)
 (23, 1, '', '', 7)]
```

My pylint plugin gives an error that `'Module' numpy has no 'cast' member` yet when I print cast I get a result of objects and lambdas with dtypes. How exactly does cast work to help me setup 'headings' for these numpy arrays and how can I then access fields using attributes? I am also missing my string columns. Could this be due to an improper dtype statement? I've recently learned Python and am starting to learn numpy for a project and any insight would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `S` types some length:

```
datadescribe = numpy.dtype([('column1', 'i4'),
                        ('column2', 'i4'),
                        ('column3', 'S1'),
                        ('column4', 'S1'),
                        ('column5', 'i4'),
                       ])
```

produces

```
[(22, 2, 'C', 'G', 6) (4, 1, 'G', 'T', 7) (11, 1, 'G', '-', 7) (23, 1, 'G', 'T', 7)]
```

Don't worry about the `pylint` message.  It might not be fully integrated with `numpy`.  There probably is another SO question about that.

---

```
X = readarray("stack25005105.csv", datadescribe)
print X.dtype
print X.dtype.names
print X['column1']
print X['column3']
```

produces

```
[('column1', '<i4'), ('column2', '<i4'), ('column3', 'S1'), ('column4', 'S1'), ('column5', '<i4')]
('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5')
[22  4 11 23]
['C' 'G' 'G' 'G']
```

Comment: Great, that fixed the missing array items. Could you explain how `recarray` has stored my _column headings_ the SciPy cookbook eludes to? Are my datatype values _column headings_ and _dtype values_ hidden attributes?

Comment: They are 'stored' in the `dtype`, and used `X['columns1']`.  See my edit.